# If $f$ is positive decreasing and continuous on $[0, \infty)$ I want to show that $\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} f(n) \leq \int_m^{\infty} f(t) \, dt$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is positive and decreasing and continuous on $[0, \infty)$ I want to show that

$$\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} f(n) \leq \int_m^{\infty} f(t) \, dt \leq \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} f(n)$$

for all nonnegative integers $m$.

Would we induct on $m$?

Comment: No.$\,\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n \le t \le n+1$, since $f$ is decreasing, we have
$$
f(n+1) \le f(t) \le f(n)
$$
so
$$
f(n+1) \le \int_n^{n+1} f(t) dt \le f(n)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^{N+1} f(n) \le \int_m^{N+1} f(t) dt \le \sum_{n=m}^N f(n)
$$
thus by letting $N \to +\infty$
$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} f(n) \leq \int_m^{\infty} f(t) \, dt \leq \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} f(n).
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Induction is not necessary here. Show that for each $N>m+1$, $\:\sum_{n=m+1}^{N} f(n) $ is a lower Riemann sum and $\sum_{n=m}^{N} f(n)$ an upper Riemann sum of the decreasing function $f$.